# How to connect Google Data Studio with AWS RDS MySQL behind VPC?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, looker-studio

I have a AWS RDS MySQL database hosted inside VPC. I am having problem with connecting Google Data Studio since it's obviously outside the VPC.
I have enabled `Publicly Accessed` option in the RDS but still can't connect, even from MySQL Workbench.

Anyone has successfully connect between AWS RDS MySQL inside VPC and Google Data Studio? What's the setup and configuration?

Comment: I'm also trying to do this, even after whitelisting the IPs as mentioned here https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031?hl=en it does not seem to work and there's no error message

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047779/google-data-studio-aws-mysql-ssl-connection) to connect MySQL & Google Data Studio (while having SSL enabled). My latter question still needs to be answered, but I actually got MySQL Workbench to work with our AWS RDS MySQL-DB.

**Steps:**

- Add SSL access to the AWS's MySQL database user as recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport): `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'encrypted_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;`
- Add your current IP address to the AWS instance's firewall-whitelist, to allow for remote MySQL DB access.
- Add hostname, port (3306), encrypted_user (created above) and password.