# How can I connect Google Data Studio to an AWS RDS Postgres instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, looker-studio

When I go to make a new data source in Data Studio, I'm prompted to enter the client/server certificates to make a secure connection. Where can I get this client certificate and key? How can I allow Google Data Studio to connect to my RDS instance?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Add the [Google IP addresses](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) to your RDS security group inbound rule list.
2. Generate a self-signed cert. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50761783/1160828) provides instructions.

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client.key -x509 -days 365 -out client.crt`

2. Get the correct server PEM file for your region from [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)
3. Add your database user information to the form and attach your `client.crt`, `client.key` and AWS pem files.
   [image]