# Where is the AWS PostgreSQL RDS Server certificate, client certificate & client private key?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, looker-studio

I am having a problem connecting AWS (Amazon Web Services) RDS (Relational Database Service) PostgreSQL instance with Google Data Studio.

My RDS is a private DB, when I try to connect my RDS with GDS it's asking for:

- Server certificate
- Client certificate
- Client private key.

Where can I find those credentials?

[image: GDS PostgreSQL connector]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I connect Google Data Studio to an AWS RDS Postgres instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625623/how-can-i-connect-google-data-studio-to-an-aws-rds-postgres-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CA cert (apparently called server cert in that iterface) at [this link](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem), linked to from [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html).

As far as I can tell, RDS does not support client certs, so there is nothing to enter in the other two fields.  Those ones should be optional.